# Are there include guards in the standard headers/libraries?

Tags: c, include-guards

By the fact if I include `stdlib.h` into each file of my program and I do not get an re-definition error. So, the answer is yes. Right?

I'm reading the `libxml2` source code, and in `HTMLparser.c` there is this part:

```
#include <string.h>
#ifdef HAVE_CTYPE_H
#include <ctype.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
```

My question is: Why use `include guards` here?

Comment: `include guards` is something like this:`#ifndef XXX #define XXX #include <XXX.h> #endif`

Comment: See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard.  It will explain why need include guards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't include guards. These macros are set if the corresponding headers are present in the system, resp. detected during configuration. If they were included unconditionally and they are not present, the compilation would fail.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are include guards in system headers. Just take a look e.g. at "string.h":

```
/* Excerpt from GCC string.h */
/*
 *  ISO C99 Standard: 7.21 String handling  <string.h>
 */

#ifndef _STRING_H
#define _STRING_H   1
```

The defines for

```
HAVE_CTYPE_H
HAVE_STDLIB_H
```

usually come from a config header which may be generated with a `./configure` script which checks for the availability of the header files.